# Command ls or dir in ghci

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm new to Haskell.

I'm using `ghci`. I know I can move through directory with the command `:cd <dir>`. But I cannot find the command to list the files in a directory (something like Unix `ls` or Microsoft `dir`).

Is it possible to do it in GHCI?

Thank you

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can call bash command `:!ls`.

Comment: or if using on a Windows platform its, `:!dir`

Answer (score 9):

You can press `tab` after certain commands like `:load` to list the files in the working directory.

Comment: This is a partial answer (i.e. not sufficient). user needs to know how to identify what directory GHCi is run in (since it can be launched from an app launcher). Also `tab` would only provide the possibility of navigating down the directory tree, and not up it.

Answer (score 1):

:show paths

`type :?` for help in GHCI; at the bottom, there's a `Commands for displaying information` heading